# Нужна ли запятая перед "только"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Он набрал дыхание, чтобы что-то сказать, но, только открыв рот, замер и шумно выдохнул.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А мне кажется, что здесь скорее такой смысл:

*Он набрал дыхание, чтобы что-то сказать, но, **едва открыв рот**, замер и шумно выдохнул.*

**ЕДВА**. I. нареч. 1. Только что, **чуть только**.

Запятая перед *только* ставится:  деепричастный оборот обособляется, а союз НО относится к структуре предложения, а не к обороту.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Другой вариант:

*Он набрал **воздуха**, чтобы что-то сказать, но, **едва открыв рот**, замер и шумно выдохнул.*

Comment: Sharon, а как Вы относитесь к использованному словосочетанию _набрать дыхание_? Мне оно кажется неверным. Набрать можно воды в рот или воздух в легкие.

Comment: Неоднозначно отношусь. Кажется, сейчас в литературе чаще встречается выражение "набрать воздуха." Не успела Тамара набрать воздуха, чтобы заорать на незваных визитеров... [Петр Акимов. Плата за страх (2000)] Есть вокальный термин "брать дыхание." В Нацкорпусе встретилось предложение: Лейтенант умолкает, то ли собираясь с мыслями, то ли затем, чтобы набрать дыхание и одним духом выпалить то, что думает...[Д. Н. Медведев. Сильные духом (Это было под Ровно) (1948)] Он еле переводил дух, когда долез до марс-рея, и долго не мог набрать воздуха, чтоб крикнуть: [Б. С. Житков. Черные паруса (1930)]

Comment: А мне кажется, что "едва открыв" затруднительно выдохнуть "шумно" :) Поэтому я предполагаю, что "только" подразумевает "только и смог...". Конечно же, здесь много стилистических "особенностей", которые затрудняют понимание.

Comment: Здесь, наверное,  переносное значение: едва открыв рот - это едва едва начав говорить или едва собравшись что-либо сказать. Но говорить он не стал и поэтому выдохнул воздух.

Comment: Sharon, спасибо, именно это и подразумевалось.

Answer (score 1):

Эта запятая не на месте, поскольку не относится к деепричастному обороту "открыв рот". Если мысленно изъять этот оборот, проявится "только замер" (вместо того, чтобы сказать что-то). Деепричастный оборот при имеющемся порядке слов обозначает скорее предшествующее действие (открыл рот, потом замер), чем обстоятельство образа действия (замер открыв рот), и потому требует обособления. Соответственно, запятую нужно сместить, поставив её после "только":

> Он набрал дыхание, чтобы что-то сказать, но только, *открыв рот*, замер
>   и шумно выдохнул.